# Compile regex rule in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Is it possible to compile regex rules in Node.js for faster usage?

Comment: You mean something different than `var pattern = /regex/;`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

V8 compiles regexes automatically. See http://www.scribd.com/doc/16921039/V8-Internals-Building-a-High-Performance-JavaScript-Engine

Comment: Oh, nice! I'm used to Python and am relatively new to Node.js. Wasn't aware V8 does it automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Node.js is just JavaScript running on V8 so you really only have what V8 provides, namely:

```
var r = new RegExp("abc", 'i');
```

V8 will do it's own optimization, probably even on inline regexes.

Comment: If you are using regex literal such as `/abc/i`, the `new RegExp` is redundant